# Verify my site with anti-virus services. (McAfee, Webroot, Avast, Bitdefender, etc.)

Tags: google-search-console, web-hosting

When I publish a new site, it is caught by anti-virus, while it is still new. The message is always something like...

> This site is safe, but doesn't have enough history for us to let you proceed without warning you.

It is easy enough to verify my site using [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console), [Bing Webmaster Tools](https://www.bing.com/webmaster), and [Norton SafeWeb](https://safeweb.norton.com/).

However, I can't find anything like those options for McAfee, Bitdefender, Webroot, Avast, etc.

What else can I do prevent my new, but very safe, sites from showing as "too new to trust"?

Answer (score 1):

McAfee has one for free here https://www.mcafeesecure.com/start-lite

I dont know about Bitdefender, Webroot, Avast.

Answer (score 1):

If you're often caught by a virus and you aren't injecting them then it is related to your web hosting because their servers must have a virus, and on that, they have hosted your website.

I think you must go for Sucuri rather than McAfee or anything.

Comment: I'm not "often" caught by anti-virus, it's only on brand new sites. I even get that this isn't a bad thing to show by default, I am just hoping to learn about tactics to address this for genuinely good websites that are just new - it's awfully hard on entrepreneurs.

This a static website hosted using AWS S3 buckets and served using AWS CloudFront CDN behind an SSL certificate obtained using AWS Cert Manager. I don't think AWS is a hosting service associated with virus laden websites.